# Write in Excel cell when line have content

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a `.xlsx` file with content like this:

```
    A    B    C    D    
1  CNT   AA    AA   
2  CNT   AA    AA   
3 (----- empty -----)     
4  CNT   AA    AA
```

I grab a user input via:

```
cellcontent = input("Enter:")
```

I can write to single cells with the following code:

```
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active

sheet['D1'] = cellcontent
```

I want to check if the lines have content and if there is content put user input (`cellcontent`) into column "D". If there is no content (like line nr. 3) than do nothing and so on.

I can read the cell values with this:

```
sheet_ranges = wb['file.xlsx']
print(sheet_ranges['A1'].value)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Should be easy. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can read cell content with: wb = load_workbook(filename='file.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['sheet1']
print(sheet_ranges['A1'].value) but what to do with the result?

Comment: Have a look at using `ws.iter_rows()`